# How to read the csv file from local computer and display data in asp.net using C# without saving on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, csv

i want to read the CSV file using file upload control in asp.net and read the csv file from user/Local computer and display the CSV file data in gridview to store in Sql server. but i am not able get the  without storing the csv file on server.
 i do not want to save the file on server. i am trying below code

```
List<ClsSalarySlipBEL> csvlist= new List<ClsSalarySlipBEL>();
string filePath = string.Empty;
string csv_file_path = Path.GetFullPath(fucsv.PostedFile.FileName); 
string csv_file_name = Path.GetFileName(fucsv.PostedFile.FileName);
//string dir = 
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
//string csvf = Convert.ToString(fucsv.PostedFile.FileName); 
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csv_file_path);
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(csv_file_path));
List<string> searchList = new List<string>();
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    searchList.Add(line);
}
```

> how can i resolve this issue? can anyone help me? thank you in advanced
>
> var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("D:\csv\file\path.csv"));
>   i want this file path using file upload control

Comment: PostedFile class has an InputStream property.

Comment: ya but i am not getting the file path. if i put static path it will work but i want to upload csv file using file upload control.

Comment: If you don't want to save the file, it doesn't **have** a path that is accessible on the server side. As @Steve says, there's a stream attached to the `PostedFile`, and that represents the *entire* extent of the existence of the file on the server, at this point in time.

Comment: okey, so there is no any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what are you talking about. Path or FIlename are not relevant if you don't want to save the file on server, Just use the _fucsv.PostedFile.InputStream_ property into your while loop and discard everything before it

Comment: Once you have your postedFile, you can read it using:
`var reader = new StreamReader(PostedFile.InputStream);`

Comment: Alternatively you can use javascript in the page itself to read the file on the client (browser) side and do everything in the browser (using a responsive framework like React).  Then the data only hits the server when its ready to be saved to the database.

Comment: thank you all thanks for all reply